# Recurse on animation end

Tags: jquery, html, recursion

Just encountering an interesting issue,..

I have the following div of images.

```
<div class="dropDown dropDown_2">
    <div><img src="images/Super_Infographic.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/Super_Infographic.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/Super_Infographic.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/Super_Infographic.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/Super_Infographic.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/Super_Infographic.png"></div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve an effect where each image fades in **ONE** at a time.
So I have written the following JQuery recursive algorithm to do so:

```
function AnimateTimeline()
{
    $(".dropDown_2 div").each(function(index, element) {
        if(!$(this).is(":visible"))
        {               
            $(this).fadeIn(2000,function(){AnimateTimeline();});
            return false;
        }           
    });
}
```

This works, except it fades in **TWO** at a time, ie 2 fade in together, then another 2, then the final 2....
Any advice on how to fix this, or a better way to implement such functionality would be much appreciated!

Cheers guys.!
**Result (whoops):**
The `AnimateTimeline()` function was getting called twice and hence was assigning the animation twice, and then doubling the number of times in which the recursive algorithm would trigger.

Comment: I would just use an array as a queue for the objects and pop them off until empty instead of checking the `:visible` selector. It wouldn't be surprised if there was some funkiness with rendering. This is javascript after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interval function may not be as clever as a recursion, but it's probably simpler to interpret.

Some styles to hide all but the first image div:

```
.dropDown_2 > div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.dropDown_2 > div:first-child {display: block;}
```

And the script:

```
var i = 1; // second image, to account for first being shown on load
var divs = $('.dropDown_2 > div');

setInterval(function () {
    divs.fadeOut(1000);
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(1000);
    i++;

    if (i >= divs.length) {i = 0}
}, 3000);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/62d1aL1s/1)

Notice that I've positioned your divs absolutely for simplicity. This isn't necessary, but would otherwise require more sophisticated timing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This looks as though it will solve my issue, but I would also like to find out why my recursive algorithm wasn't working for future reference.. Thanks again !